# how to get Dataframe from list spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have a list of RDD. I have iterated the rdd and for each elemet of rdd I am doing some parsing logic. Finally I getting

```
 val mRdd = nRdd.map {
      ele =>  //parsing logic, I have the below field
colum = Array[String]  // example ['id','name','dept']<br> 
c_type = Array[String]  // example ['Int','String','String']<br> 
value = ArrayBuffer[String] //   [1,lucy,it][2,denis,cs]<br>
}
```

How I can get the list of dataframe in `mRdd`

I tried a logic to create dataframe, in this case I have to rdd first. But I can't create rdd inside rdd.

I am new in spark. I am using spark 1.6.3 
Please help me

Comment: Please show the initial input. If you have a list of RDD, you're probably doing something wrong

Comment: For starters, it looks like you want a case class `Person(id, name, dept)`

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert an RDD into a Dataframe, you would need to do the following:

**Approach 1 - Use createDaframe function**:

```
val mRdd: Seq[DataFrame] = nRdd.map {ele =>
    val parsedRDD = ele //apply parse logic here

    val schema = StructType(Seq(
        StructField("id", IntegerType),
        StructField("name", StringType),
        StructField("dept", StringType)
    ))
    createDataframe(parsedRDD, schema)
}
```

Read more about this approach here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema

**Approach 2 - Use toDF implicit function**:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val mRdd: Seq[DataFrame] = nRdd.map {ele =>
    val parsedRDD = ele //apply parse logic here
    val columns = Seq("id", "name", "dept")
    parsedRDD.toDF(columns: _*)
}
```

Comment: in first approach, I have field type also. How I can apply field type for each column in dataframe.?

Comment: I've fixed the first approach to use a schema instead of field names.

Comment: you can't create parsedRDD inside the rdd (nRdd)